# Loading Dependent Drop Down Options while Web Scraping

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from the following website:
http://www.equibase.com/stats/View.cfm?tf=meet&tb=jockey&rbt=TB

I want the VBA Code to do the following steps:

1. Go to the URL
2. Click on "Jockeys"
3. Select a Track from the Drop-Down List. Say, select "ALBUQUERQUE"
4. Based on the selected track, the page loads the "Available Meets" Dropdown.

Now I want to select the first meet from this drop-down

My code is selecting the value "ALBUQUERQUE" from the first dropdown but is not loading the data in the second drop-down.

```
Sub extract()

Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim doc As New HTMLDocument
Dim optionText As String

optionText = "ALBUQUERQUE"
ie.Visible = True
Url = "http://www.equibase.com/stats/View.cfm?tf=meet&amp;tb=jockey&amp;rbt=TB"
ie.Navigate Url

Application.StatusBar = "Navigating to URL..."

Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Do While ie.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

Set doc = ie.Document

Set jockeyButton = doc.getElementsByClassName("scMainTab")
   
For Each Button In jockeyButton
    If Button.getAttribute("href") = "#jockey" Then
        Button.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next Button

Set tracksDropdown = doc.getElementById("selAvailTracks")

''AT THIS POINT, IT SHOULD AUTOMATICALLY LOAD THE SECOND DROP DOWN BUT IT IS NOT HAPPENING

ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

How can I select the first item from the second drop-down list?

Comment: Just another information, I am using IE11. I think it can be a compatibility issue. Please help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic word is "html event". To make the selection in a dropdown effective, its change-event must be triggered. Otherwise nothing happens.

You cannot put "ALBUQUERQUE" in the first dropdown. The value for "ALBUQUERQUE" is "ALB:USA"

```html
<select id="selAvailTracks" name="selAvailTracks" class="scTrackSelects">
  <option value=""> Available Tracks </option>
  <option value="ALB:USA">ALBUQUERQUE</option>
  <option value="AQU:USA">AQUEDUCT</option>
  <option value="ARP:USA">ARAPAHOE PARK</option>
  <option value="AZD:USA">ARIZONA DOWNS</option>
  <option value="AP :USA">ARLINGTON</option>
  <option value="ASD:CAN">ASSINIBOIA DOWNS</option>
  <option value="ATO:USA">ATOKAD DOWNS</option>
  <option value="BEL:USA">BELMONT PARK</option>
  ...
  ...
  ...
```

Another way to select is the index of the desired element. This is used for dropdown no. 2.

Try this macro to make the selection including dropdown 2:

```
Sub Extract()

'Declare all variables
Dim url As String
Dim browser As Object
Dim htmlDoc As Object
Dim nodeTracksDropdown As Object
Dim dateDropdown As Object
Dim trackInDropdown As String

  'Initialize variables
  trackInDropdown = "ALB:USA" 'You can also get this from a cell of a table
  url = "http://www.equibase.com/stats/View.cfm?tf=meet&tb=jockey&rbt=TB"

  'Initialize Internet Explorer, set visibility,
  'call URL and wait until page is fully loaded
  Set browser = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
  browser.Visible = True
  browser.navigate url
  Do Until browser.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
  'Short break to load dynamic content
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3))

  'Shortening document reference
  Set htmlDoc = browser.document

  'Get first dropdown, select track, trigger change event
  'and wait a second to set up the second dropdown
  Set nodeTracksDropdown = htmlDoc.getElementById("selAvailTracks")
  nodeTracksDropdown.Value = trackInDropdown
  Call TriggerEvent(htmlDoc, nodeTracksDropdown, "change")
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1))

  'Get second dropdown, select second entry, trigger change event
  'and wait a second to set up the following elements
  Set dateDropdown = htmlDoc.getElementById("selAvailRaceMeets")
  dateDropdown.selectedIndex = 1
  Call TriggerEvent(htmlDoc, dateDropdown, "change")
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1))

  'Do whatever you want here
  '...
  '...
  '...

  'Clean up
  'browser.Quit
  'Set browser = Nothing
  'Set nodeTracksDropdown = Nothing
  'Set dateDropdown = Nothing
End Sub
```

This procedure to triger html events:

```
Private Sub TriggerEvent(htmlDocument As Object, htmlElementWithEvent As Object, eventType As String)

  Dim theEvent As Object

  htmlElementWithEvent.Focus
  Set theEvent = htmlDocument.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
  theEvent.initEvent eventType, True, False
  htmlElementWithEvent.dispatchEvent theEvent
End Sub
```